# AWS Glue Crawler on Another Account's S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-glue

The partners account has given me a role that I can assume for access to the s3 bucket,

I created a role for the glue crawler and have attached an inline policy which lets me assume the role given to me by the partner.

The policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::AWSID:role/RoleToAssume"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

I have also attached AWSGlueServiceRole and AmazonS3FullAccess.

I have added the specific bucket and prefix to the targets of the glue crawler.

When I start the crawler I keep getting "User does not have access to target s3://ParnterBucker/ID/Name/Date/"

When I use the below code in boto3, I have access to the S3 objects with the partner_s3_client and partner_s3_resource and The same naming works.

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts',aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'])


assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
RoleArn=f"ROLE",
RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession")

assumed_role_credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

partner_s3_client = boto3.client(
's3',
aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
aws_session_token=assumed_role_credentials['SessionToken'],
)

partner_s3_resource = boto3.resource(
's3',
aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
aws_session_token=assumed_role_credentials['SessionToken'],
)
```

Are there any other policies or permissions that I am missing for me to crawl the partners buckets?

Answer (score 0):

There should be two Policy and You need to attach the trust Policy also in order to crawl cross account S3 bucket .

Here is the full documentation .[Granting cross-account access using an IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/cross-account-access.html)

Follow the section **Granting cross-account access using an IAM role**

Dont forget to add trust Policy without that it wont work .